# Cleaning up partitions after several failed attempts to install Ubuntu 20

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

My PC had been running Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12 for a long time. I recently upgraded to Windows 10 and had problems with Grub not finding Windows. I tried installing Ubuntu 20 alongside the others but it was not running properly (freezing, requiring reboot).

Long story short: I fixed the master boot record using boot-repair and now Windows 10 loads directly without the Grub menu. I have cleaned up the disks to remove multiple versions of Ubuntu.

There are now 4 partitions on my primary disk, a 500 GB Samsung SSD:

C: NTFS 395 GB: (this is where Windows OS is)

*: Hidden drive, NTFS 521 MB

G: FAT32 512 MB: EFI folder with BOOT and ubuntu subfolders

H: NTFS 69 GB: this was where 2 instances of ubuntu were previously located. I deleted the partitions and reformatted in NTFS.

I would like to get rid of the G partition. Does this only contain Ubuntu boot files or are there also Windows files there?

Structure of G:

EFI/Boot:

BOOT64.EFI

fbx64.efi

mmx64.efi

EFI/ubuntu:

BOOT64.CSV

grub.cfg

grubx64.efi

mmx64.efi

shimx64.efi

Again, Windows is using Legacy boot, not efi. This was an upgrade from Windows 7, NOT a clean install of Windows 10.

Also, should I leave some unallocated space on the SSD. I read somewhere that the SSD can use it in case of errors??

Thanks,
Barry

Comment: I suggest that you format (erase) the entire disk as GPT and reinstall Windows 10 then Ubuntu as new UEFI installations.  If you originally had W7, you probably have a MBR partition scheme instead of GPT. It's ancient and can be cumbersome to work with.  Tip: create a dummy "placeholder" partition at the end of the disk to reserve space for Ubuntu that you can delete after installing Windows, freeing up unpartitioned free space that will make Ubuntu installation easier with the "Install alongside Windows" guided install.

Comment: Before that, find out why your Ubuntu installations have failed.  Do you have valid installation media?  Does it pass integrity checks?

Comment: Please clarify your release(s).  Ubuntu uses *yy* releases only for specialist *snap* only releases for IoT appliances/devices or cloud based use (having done so since 2016). Main releases use *yy.mm* such as used by server & desktops releases (and are the more powerful).

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I used Ubuntu 20.04.1-desktop-amd64. I had problems getting it to run after installing and also freezing of the live CD. I next used an older live CD of 16.04 LTS and that worked normally. I used that for the boot-repair program. I was reluctant to perform a clean installation of Windows 10 since I have a lot of applications that would need to be reinstalled.